# Creating an app to provide user with offline map and offline routing using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, openstreetmap, osmand, osmandmapcreator

I am trying to create a mockup of application that will allow user to use the app to navigate in a city.

The reason the map needed to be online is that my application needs to modify the mockup traffic light in the map based on traffic.

Currently I tried to OSM since Google map doesn't provide any traffic light data.

My problem is I have no idea how to create an offline map, by using OSMAnd, I am able to create an OBF file using OsmAndMapCreator, after that I have no idea how to implement it (I cannot find any tutorial online).

I also don't know which offline routing service to used, I have find that OSMAnd can be used to provide navigation but I don't know how to implement it in a new app.

I am sorry if this is off topic or being a vague question, but I have no more choice.

Thank you.

Comment: Checkout the api from tomtom.

Comment: @Nitin Thanks you for your suggestion, will give it a try

Comment: You could use OsmAnd with a custom online router. Implement the online router yourself. Then you can use OsmAnd to access your router from your device, to display the resulting route on a map and use it for navigation.

Comment: @scai I have the problem that I have no idea how to actually implement OsmAnd in my app using Android Studio, I cannot seem to find any good documentation on using OsmAnd API and is confused by the different terms.

Comment: @LeeLapHerng You don't have to "implement OsmAnd". Just install it on your phone and let it use your own routing engine. OsmAnd already supports various online routers (OSRM, YOURS) out of the box. It can also be enhanced by additional routing engines, this is for example done by [brouter](http://brouter.de/brouter/offline.html).

Comment: @scai I don't think I can just used the OsmAnd directly because I have to create a new application that can do offline routing and map (just in a single city), I am still confused by whether to use OSMDroid or OSMand

Comment: Take a look at mapsforge or maybe MapBox GL, not sure if it offers offline routing though. This wiki page should be helpful: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android